# I need to build a URL with nested arrays

Tags: php, url, filemaker

I am trying to construct the URL that would result from some sample PHP code.  The code is:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
// CONNECT TO API, VERIFY MY API KEY AND PASSWORD AND GET THE LEAD DATA
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://app.kartradev.com/api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query(
        array(
            'app_id' => 'AIm863DwsOW',
            'api_key' => 'QG9GPLW8G',
            'api_password' => 'kdwFAfwrfVS',
            'get_lead' => array(
                'email' => 'JoeSmith@domain.com',
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

I am using FileMaker to make and send the URL.  If I send this string with an incorrect password:

https://app.kartra.com/api?app_id=BnFTjKPVdrGO&api_password=eMEaKWSfUQXu&api_key=YnvDR

I get this response indicating that I am successful in querying the API:

> {
>     "message": "API credentials are not valid. Please get an API key and API password first",
>     "status": "Error",
>     "type": "203"
>   }

The array being built by the php code is what is tripping me up.  I have tried quite a few variations, for example:

https://app.kartra.com/api?app_id=BnFTjKPVO&api_password=eMEaK&api_key=YnvGdT&getlead[email]=rk@somewhere.com

I always get this result:

> {
>     "status": "Error",
>     "message": "'actions' not an array",
>     "type": "224"
>   }

I have requested help from the api tech support people, but this is a brand new API and they have not replied yet (they are rolling out their site by Monday and are very busy).

My question:  Given that code above, what would the resulting url look like?

Edited:

Here is the full json response I got with Matt's suggestions on 4/1/18:

Thanks, @MattGibson!  I tried your suggestion, got back the same error as before.  I also tried tex/plain and application/json.  Here is the full JSON response I always get:   {
   "body": "{\"status\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"'actions' not an array\",\"type\":\"224\"}",
   "code": 200,
   "headers": {
      "CF-RAY": 4.054e+96,
      "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
      "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
      "Date": "Mon, 02 Apr 2018 17:10:49 GMT",
      "Expect-CT": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
      "Expires": "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Server": "cloudflare",
      "Set-Cookie": "ci_session=d47fe563bbbe215ab4f936ce1a951e0d28d39d57; expires=Mon, 02-Apr-2018 20:10:49 GMT; Max-Age=10800; path=/; secure; HttpOnly",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
      "Vary": "Accept-Encoding"
   },
   "status": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
}

Comment: Bear in mind that `CURLOPT_POST` will send the data as an [HTTP POST request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)), with the variables in the *body* of the request, *not* as URL parameters. The URL will therefore simply look like `https://app.kartradev.com/api`.

Comment: can you send us some link to api docs?

Comment: (I don't know much about Filemaker, but [this documentation](https://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/importing-http-request.html) seems to suggest you should use `httpspost` as your URL scheme to send a POST request, with the parameters you have.)

Comment: The first thing I'd do is use an API-testing tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to get something that definitely worked, then go from there...

Comment: Hi Lulco.  Here is the API info:   https://documentation.kartra.com/category/api/

Comment: Interesting. I'd guess that the documentation is wrong. From the looks of it, I'd probably try sending an *action* of `get_lead`, with your lead's email address in a `lead` array (as in the first PHP example.)

Answer (score 0):

you should add GET-parameters to the query URL, not the POST fields.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://app.kartradev.com/api?".http_build_query($params));
```

Comment: ["If query_data is an array, it may be a simple one-dimensional structure, or an array of arrays (which in turn may contain other arrays)."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) -- I think the original code in the question will work fine.

Comment: Yes you're right.The first line is wrong in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I'lll pass that correction back to the people who wrote the API.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP result of that `http_build_query` would be:

app_id=AIm863DwsOW&api_key=QG9GPLW8G&api_password=kdwFAfwrfVS&get_lead%5Bemail%5D=JoeSmith%40domain.com

...so the whole URL would be simply

https://app_id=AIm863DwsOW&api_key=QG9GPLW8G&api_password=kdwFAfwrfVS&get_lead%5Bemail%5D=JoeSmith%40domain.com

However, given that it's sent as a POST request (`CURLOPT_POST = 1`), that's not really what gets sent to the server. In fact, you'd actually hit the base URL `https://app.kartradev.com/api`, with your parameters sent in the body of the POST request in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

So to replicate your example code in Filemaker, you'd need to do whatever Filemaker needs to send the request as a POST with the parameters in the appropriate format in the body.

In total, given your PHP code, the result would be an HTTP POST request that looked like this:

```
POST /api HTTP/1.1
Host: app.kartradev.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app_id=AIm863DwsOW&api_key=QG9GPLW8G&api_password=kdwFAfwrfVS&get_lead%5Bemail%5D=JoeSmith%40domain.com
```

Comment: I sent exactly that string with a post and received the same answer as before (not an array).  I also sent it with a GET and received the same response.

Comment: Also the httpspost command you reference is not a valid FileMaker command ( I wish it was...).

Comment: Thanks, @MattGibson!  I tried your suggestion, got back the same error as before.  I also tried tex/plain and application/json.  Here is the full JSON response I always get (in next message)